# List occurrences in list of lists

Tags: python, list

We have a list containing lists like so:

```
My_list = [ [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[1,2,3] ]
```

Is there an easy way to learn that the list item `[1,2,3]` appears twice in `My_list`? I am not interested in the individual numbers but i am interested in them as a list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I count the occurrences of a list item in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `list.count()` in order to find the occurrence of item in the `list` as:

```
>>> My_list.count([1, 2, 3])
2
```

Comment: I have tried it like so:
'for x in My_list
print(MyList.count(x))' 
Not working

Comment: @ThanosMygdalias presumably because that isn't syntactically valid Python. I'd recommend a tutorial.

Comment: Did you had `:` after the My_list as `for x in My_list: print My_list.count(x)`?  It will work

Comment: @down-voter: Please also mention the reason, so that I could correct my mistake or improve my answer if it lacks something :)

Comment: Well actually it was far worse -_- I have another list with a similar name and autocomplete did its job :p Was looking at the wrong list. *embarrassed*  Yeah it works, thanks